# Type "someViewContoller" does not conform to protocol "UITablViewDataSource"

Tags: ios, swift

I am really new to the whole Swift thing and also programming in general. I have researched everywhere but couldn't find an answer for the error that I got. Please help me :)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TümÜrünlerViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tümÜrünlerTableView: UITableView!
    @IBAction func cancelTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    var ürünler = ["Havalı", "Daha Havalı", "Eheheh"]
    var ürün = "Balık"

    func TableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        var cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel!.text = self.ürünler[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.ürün = self.ürünler[indexPath.row]
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("başlıklardanÖzeleSegue", sender: self)            
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.tümÜrünlerTableView.dataSource = self
        self.tümÜrünlerTableView.delegate = self
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {            
        var detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as BaşlıklarViewController
        detailViewController.ürün = self.ürün

        if self.ürün == "Havalı" {
            detailViewController.label = "anan"
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ->Int {
        return self.ürünler.count
    }
}
```

Here is my code but I am getting the error when I try to insert UITableViewDataSource. I tried everything that the forums said but it docent seem to work for me :(

Answer (score 1):

My guess:

Let us look at this method. T needs to be decapitalized. tableView not TableView

```
func TableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{


    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel!.text = self.ürünler[indexPath.row]
    return cell




}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a very simple mistake - the `UITableViewDataSource` requires that 2 methods are implemented:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

but you've just made a typo in the 2nd one:

```
func TableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     ^
```

the method name should start in lowercase: `tableView(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You have a capital T on your cellForRowAtIndexPath function. It should read:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel!.text = self.ürünler[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason behind error is that, you are not calling `datasource` required method in correct order. Correct order of calling is :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Always, make sure you call `numberOfRowsInSection` before `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.